# How to correctly install OpenOPC?

Tags: python, pycharm, opc

Trying to connect Python to an OPC simulated server using OpenOPC. I am able to connect to the server, but when I try to read an item I get `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. Could this be a problem with the installation of the OpenOPC package?

I am running:
- Windows 10 Pro 64 bits
- Python 3.7 64 bits
- PyCharm
- Graybox OPC DA Auto Wrapper x64
- Pyro 4
- Pywin32
- Matrikon OPC

I have tried running PyCharm as administrator to fix any permission issues, but I still get the same error.

```
>>> import OpenOPC    
>>> opc = OpenOPC.client()    
>>> opc.servers()    
['AspenTech.OTS_OPCServer.30', 'Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6', 'Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1']    
>>> opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation')    
>>> opc.read('Random.Real8')    
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OPC uses COM to talk to the Matrikon server, it could be that the 64-bit version of Python is encountering an error.  I have had some similar issues when attempting to do ctypes when someone tries to use a 64-bit version of python to talk to a 32-bit interface.  If I were you I would try with 32-bit Python and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to make it work with Python 2.7, I think there might be compatitivity issues with the 3.7 version.